# Exception has occurred: NameError name 'C_F' is not defined (Python)

Tags: python, nameerror

The error of my code is like this: Exception has occurred: NameError name 'C_F' is not defined

Python said the C_F function is not defined, but I did.

Here is my code:

```py
class temperature:
    class transform:
        def __init__(self, f, t, T):
            self.tem_from = f
            self.tem_to = t
            self.tem = float(T)

        def C_F(self):
            CT = self.tem
            FT = 32 + 1.8 * CT
            return (FT)

        def all(self):
            if self.tem_from == 'C':
                if self.tem_to == 'F':
                    C_F()


temperature.transform('C', 'F', 0).all()
```

If you know what to do, please answer this, thank you!

Comment: You are missing reference to *self* - `self.C_F()`

Comment: Thank you for answering this, the problem fixed.